# Alexa add to favourites

Tags: json, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

Am working on a skill with content and i would like to have an option that user can add something to their favourite list and ask Alexa to send an email with all favourites including links. (what is the best way to to this)

Each item has a link to a website.

Could someone help or point me in w right direction/tutorial/example
am not sure is it better to use db/API/hardcode for content.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of the content going into the fav list and a sample link.

Comment: for example if you have a recipes skill - 50 recipes in breakfast category, 100 in lunch and 200 in dinner. Each recipe has a external link to a website but just for email option so after user creates list of favourites and wants Alexa to send email with those recipes, it will create an email with a tile of the recipe and link.

Comment: Do you want to add it to fav list while the user is navigating through different recipes in a category.

Comment: while is listening - so alexa is saying lets say ingredients and how to do it and user can add to fav